# How to parse a WebSocket response to a list of objects

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, socket.io, kotlin-coroutines

I am using Socket IO to fetch data from the API in JSON format

In my ListViewModal I have:

```
 private fun getTorrentsSocketIO() {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        try {
            val socket = IO.socket("...")
            socket.on("torrents") {
                _torrents.postValue(...???...)
            }
            socket.connect()
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            Log.i("LIST_VIEW_MODEL", t.message.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

socket.on is returning an array of type any if I see correctly

How can I parse the response to a `List<Torrent>` cause I want to update my `_torrent` live data

I am using moshi as my json converter

Torrent class looks like this

```
data class Torrent(
  val name: String,
  val magnetURI: String,
  val length: Double,
  val received: Double,
  val downloaded: Double,
  val uploaded: Double,
  val downloadSpeed: Double,
  val uploadSpeed: Double,
  val progress: Double,
  val ratio: Double,
  val paused: Boolean,
  val done: Boolean
)
```

And json response like this

```
[
  {
    "name":"Sintel",
    "magnetURI":"",
    "length":123.31236934661865,
    "received":46.98424434661865,
    "downloaded":46.98424434661865,
    "uploaded":0,
    "downloadSpeed":0,
    "uploadSpeed":0,
    "progress":0.38101809733742664,
    "ratio":0,
    "paused":true,
    "done":false
  }
]
```

Also if anyone has a recommendation on how to make this code nicer, please answer

I tried multiple things, but I always get `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING` error

Answer (score 0):

You need to objectify the string you get as json via Moshi.

```
    val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    val adapter: JsonAdapter<Torrent> = moshi.adapter(Torrent::class.java)
    val torrent= adapter.fromJson(torrentJsonStr))
```

Comment: This only assigns a single Torrent file. I want to create a List<Torrent>

Comment: Using the for loop, you can store and use each object you create with moshi in an array.

Comment: As a different logic, create a new data class and define a value (List <Torrent>). You can objectify Json this way.

Comment: sample : https://github.com/square/moshi#built-in-type-adapters

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing this:

```
private fun getTorrentsSocketIO() {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        try {
            val socket = IO.socket("...")
            socket.on("torrents") {
                val responseBody = it[0].toString()
                val torrents = Gson().fromJson(responseBody, Array<Torrent>::class.java).toList()
                _torrents.postValue(torrents)
            }
            socket.connect()
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            Log.i("LIST_VIEW_MODEL", t.message.toString())
        }
    }
}
```